# What would be the best font size for text on iPhone

Tags: iphone, font-size

In general, what'll be the best font size for text - or put in this way, what are the font size used in iPhone settings app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font System size 17.0

Appears to be the general settings font size.  It may be in bold, making the characters thicker, but 17 is the size.